# Returning a type, not an instance

Tags: types, return, rust, traits

Is there a way in Rust to return a type that implements certain trait from a function (I do not want the instance, but the type). Something like this (which does not work in its current form):

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn sum(&self, val: i64) -> i64;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct X {
    x: i64,
}

impl MyTrait for X {
    fn sum(&self, val: i64) -> i64 {
        self.x + 2 * val
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Y {
    x: i64,
}

impl MyTrait for Y {
    fn sum(&self, val: i64) -> i64 {
        self.x + 3 * val
    }
}

fn from_name(name: &str) -> MyTrait {
    match name {
        "X" => X,
        "Y" => Y,
        _ => panic!("Unknown name")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = X{x: 21};
    let y = Y{x: 42};

    // This does not work, it is just to show the idea
    let z = from_name("X"){x: 10};

    println!("x {:?}", x.sum(3));
    println!("y {:?}", y.sum(3));
    println!("z {:?}", z.sum(3));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to what you're asking is a factory function:

```
fn from_name(name: &str) -> Box<Fn(i64) -> Box<MyTrait>> {
    match name {
        "X" => Box::new(|x| Box::new(X{x: x})),
        "Y" => Box::new(|x| Box::new(Y{x: x})),
        _ => panic!("Unknown name"),
    }
}

fn example() -> i64 {
    let factory = from_name("X");
    let z = factory(10);
    z.sum(10)
}
```

`from_name` returns a function which returns an object.

Comment: NB, you can do this without having to have a closure, and possibly even without having to have a `Box<MyTrait>` trait object, via enums e.g. `enum Maker { X, Y }` returned by `from_name` with a method like `fn make(&self, i64) -> Value`, where `enum Value { X(X), Y(Y) }`.